# Induction regarding Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, stirling-numbers

I was wondering how to prove this by induction $$S(m,m-1)=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}.$$ Any help is appreciative.

Comment: What is $S$ ???

Comment: Is $S$ the Stirling number of the second kind?

Comment: Yes @cansomeonehelpmeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the recurrence for the Stirling numbers,
$$S(m,m-1)=S(m-1,m-2)+(m-1)S(m-1,m-1).$$
If you know what $S(m-1,m-1)$ is, this gives a basis for induction.

Comment: (+1). I didn't realize until now that OP was asking for a proof by *induction* specifically.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to do base case like this. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $S(m,m-1)$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), you need to partition $m$ elements into $m-1$ sets. This means that exactly one set has to contain $2$ elements, can you continue from here?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I am new in induction so it's not very clear to me. But thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, you got one set which consists of $2$ elements, say $\{a,b\}$. All of the other sets contain just $1$ element, so you don't have to worry about them. Now, in how may different ways can you make the set $\{a,b\}$ with $2$ elements?

Comment: Just one way I guess?! since {a,b} and {b,a} are same

Comment: You're right that $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,a\}$ are the same, but how many options are there for $a$, and how many are there for $b$?

Comment: 2 for each of them

Comment: You got $m$ elements, so $a$ can take $m$ different values, right? What about $b$?

Comment: Is it m-1 for b?

Comment: That's right! So you can choose $a$ in $m$ possible ways, and $b$ in $m-1$ possible ways. So how many different sets with $2$ elements can you make?

Comment: m(m-1)? I am sorry I am kinda dumb in doing proofs

Comment: No need to apologize. Yes, you're right that there are $m(m-1)$ ways, but you said $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,a\}$ are the same sets, so you have to divide the total number by $2$ to get $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$, since we're counting double.

Comment: @Dana I just realized that you were asking for a proof by *induction* specifically. Although this is a proof, it's not a proof by *induction*. You should see **Lord Shark**'s comment.

Comment: Ohhhh Ok, got it! Thank you so much for your patience! I actually thought induction is the only way to prove it.  But never thought of this way

Answer (score 0):

Recall, the *Stirling numbers of the second kind* $S(n,k)$ is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into $k$ distinct groups.

For this proof, we will use the recurrence $$S(n,k)=kS(n-1,k)+S(n-1,k-1).$$

**Base case.** Take $m=2$; then, we have $S(2,1)=1.$ There is only one way to partition a set of two elements in $1$ group. Also $2(2-1)/2=1.$ So this is fine.

**Inductive hypothesis.** Assume true for $m$; that is $$S(m,m-1)=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}.$$
**Inductive step.** Now, let's try it for $m+1$. We have \begin{align}S(m+1,m)&=mS(m,m)+S(m,m-1),\\
&=m+\frac{m(m-1)}{2},\\
&=\frac{2m+m^2-m}{2},\\
&=\frac{m^2+m}{2},\\
&=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}, \end{align}
as required.

Do let me know if you are still confused with anything.

Comment: I was actually trying to prove m(m-1)/2

Comment: That's fine. With the inductive step; you prove it's true for the $m+1^{th}$ case; that is, substitute $m+1$ in the identity you are trying to prove.

Comment: You mean set S(m+1,m) and then prove it? But in that way its giving me m(m+1)/2

Comment: Yes. Set $S(m+1,m)$ and prove $m(m+1)/2,$ which we have done if you follow through the proof for the inductive step.

Comment: I am not sure about one thing. How can I prove m(m-1)/2 by proving m(m+1)/2?

Comment: Here, have a read of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)